# How does the JIT Compiler treat value types?

Tags: c#, jit

I am reading **C# in depth by Jon Skeet**. Quoting from the third chapter:

> The JIT can treat value types in a particularly clever way that
>   manages to eliminate boxing and unboxing in many situations. In some
>   cases, this can make a huge difference to performance in terms of both
>   speed and memory consumption.

Could someone please explain what this means exactly, preferably with an example?

Comment: *Boxing* describes the process of saving a value type as an `object`, for instance: `object o = 13;`, whereas *unboxing* describes the process of retrieving the value from the object: `int thirteen = (int)o;`. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: NO. I want to the precise meaning of the above statement "The JIT can treat value types in a particularly clever way that manages to eliminate boxing and unboxing in many situations. In some cases, this can make a huge difference to performance in terms of both speed and memory consumption."

Comment: Answering this question is dangerous, Jon has a lot of fans.  But afaik he's mistaken (dodging that bolt of lightning).  The SSCLI20 version of the jitter certainly always boxes a value type when the compiler asked for a box.  It is the C# compiler that can elide a box by using Opcodes.Constrained instead of Opcodes.Box.  Then again, that version of the jitter isn't a match with the one we use every day, maybe there's a corner case in a generic method that allows eliding the box at runtime, it's feasible.

Comment: @HansPassant: I wasn't speaking about anything at that level - nor I guess is it really specific to the JIT. It's more that situations which would have required boxing in C# 1 don't require boxing in C# 2, and the JIT doesn't go through a *pointless* boxing operation. I wasn't trying to suggest that it ignores any boxing that the compiler requires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take `List<int>` as an example. That is backed by a genuine `int[]`, and the JIT will JIT-compile the code specifically for the `int` type argument, so that any code using a `T` within `List<T>` should get any optimizations as if the code had been written *just* for integers.

Compare this with Java's generics, where the only valid type arguments are class types - so even though it's valid to write:

```
// Java code!
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
integers.add(10);
int x = integers.get(0); // x = 10
```

That performs a boxing and unboxing operation in the background. The equivalent C# code would involve no boxing at all.

Comment: Many many thanks Jon.But Jon Could u plz exaplain the below mentioned line more elaboretly. The line is :so that any code using a T within List<T> should get any optimizations as if the code had been written just for integers.

Answer (score 0):

I think Jon ment that many of these types is not treated as objects of its defining type. For example; an int does not have to be treated as a struct and can be handled directly in registers. Adding two integers is not handled by overloaded operator calls but done by cpu directly.